# Interchangable Multikey Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have many entities that need to share data between themselves. Both entities will request values from this dictionary.

```
public class Key {
    public string nameA;
    public string nameB;
}
public class SharedValue {
    public int id;
}

private Dictionary<Key, SharedValue> relation = new Dictionary<Key, SharedValue>();
```

Then adding to the dictionary.

```
relation.Add(new Key(){ nameA = "User1", nameB = "User2" }, new SharedValue(){ id = -11 });
```

Finally I was hoping I could get a shared SharedValue no matter of the order of nameA or nameB.

```
relation[new Key(){ nameA = "User1", nameB = "User2" }].id  // Get -11
relation[new Key(){ nameA = "User2", nameB = "User1" }].id  // Get -11
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what your question is?

Comment: As long as `Key` doesn't override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` a standard implementation will be used for generating the hashcode for your `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `Equals` and `GeyHashCode` methods for your key class:

```
    public class Key
    {
        public string nameA;
        public string nameB;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj as Key);
        }

        protected bool Equals(Key other)
        {
            return string.Equals(nameA, other.nameA) && string.Equals(nameB, other.nameB) ||
                   string.Equals(nameA, other.nameB) && string.Equals(nameB, other.nameA);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (nameA?.GetHashCode() ^ nameB?.GetHashCode()) ?? 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not `Equals` which is necessary for the dictionary key but `GetHashCode` and then `Equals`(always both)

Comment: For Equality comparison in my view `IEquatable<Key>` is a better choice. Overriden Equals and GetHashCode could be directed to the `IEquatable<Key>.Equals(Key k)` and `IEquatable<Key>.GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 1):

You could provide a cutom `IEqualityComparer<Key>` which you can use for the dictionary constructor  (and many LINQ methods as well):

```
public class UnorderedKeyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Key>
{
    public bool Equals(Key x, Key y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        if (string.Equals(x.NameA, y.NameA) && string.Equals(x.NameB, y.NameB))
            return true;
        if (string.Equals(x.NameA, y.NameB) && string.Equals(x.NameB, y.NameA))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Key obj)
    {
        return (obj?.NameA?.GetHashCode() ?? int.MinValue) ^ (obj?.NameB?.GetHashCode() ?? int.MinValue);
    }
}
```

So in this case you just need to initialize the dictionary with the `UnorderedKeyComparer`:

```
Dictionary<Key, SharedValue> Relation = new Dictionary<Key, SharedValue>(new UnorderedKeyComparer());
```

By the way, i couldn't resist to fix your naming issues.

Comment: A n1 solution :) Imho overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is a bit of an overkill for this task and also it can potentially lead to issues...

Comment: No worries, I'll have to look up on proper formatting.

Comment: Using `IEquatable<Key>` in my view is a better choice. `EqualityComparer<Key>` needs to be explicitly supplied. In fact we can direct object class overridden methods to IEquatable<Key> implementation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: there is no better or worse, both have different pros and cons. What if you don't want to compare the keys unordered? If you override `Equals`(or implement `IEquatable<>`) you can't change this behaviour anymore, never. The `IEqualityComparer<>` enables you to provide one comparer here and another type somewhere else. It's reusable without breaking existing code or setting in stone the `Equals` implementation. You can use the code above easily to implement `IEquatable<Key>`, i just wanted to provide the most flexible and lightweight approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I get your point, but IEquatable is like a default implementation, if we have access to the source code and that still doesn't prevent us from using the IEqualityComparer. Somewhere expecting end user to supply the default equality doesn't always forebode well and is mostly delegated back to Object.Equals

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, examples are:

1. Implement `IEqualityComparer<YourKey>` and pass an instance of a
   class implements `IEqualityComparer<YourKey>` to the constructor of the
   dictionary
2. Implement `IEquatable<T>` on your custom key only.

This is how to do `Option 2`:

```
public class Key:IEquatable<Key> {
    public string nameA;
    public string nameB;

    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        if(other == null)
            return false;
        if(ReferenceEquals(this,other))
            return true;
        return (string.Equals(this.nameA,other.nameA) && string.Equals(this.nameB,other.nameB))
                || (string.Equals(this.nameA,other.nameB) && string.Equals(this.nameB,other.nameA));
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj){
        if(obj == null)
            return false;
        if(ReferenceEquals(obj,this))
            return true;
        return Equals((Key)obj);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode(){
        return (nameA?.GetHashCode() ^ nameB?.GetHashCode()) ?? 0;
    }
 }
```

Testing:

```
private static Dictionary<Key, SharedValue> relation = new Dictionary<Key, SharedValue>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    relation.Add(new Key{nameA="a",nameB="b"},new SharedValue{id=1});
    if(relation.ContainsKey(new Key{nameA="a",nameB="b"})){
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
    }
    if(relation.ContainsKey(new Key{nameA="b",nameB="a"})){
        Console.WriteLine("YES");
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

Output:

```
YES
YES
```